# change image and text at specified period of interval

Tags: jquery, html

I have some images in a list. I want to change the image one by one every 30 seconds. And i have placed 2 images for previous and next, on click previous or next the image should change.

I have no idea how to do this.

My code is,

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider_below">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="assets/img/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="Slider 1" title="Slider 1" />
                <div class="text" align="center">
                    <h1>Clearence Sale</h1>
                    <h1>Get upto 50% Off</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="next_button">
                    <img src="assets/img/prev.png" alt="Slider Previous" title="Slider Previous" class="prev" />
                    <img src="assets/img/next.png" alt="Slider Next" title="Slider Next" class="next" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="assets/img/slider/slider2.jpg" alt="Slider 2" title="Slider 2" />
                <div class="text" align="center">
                    <h1>Clearence Sale</h1>
                    <h1>Get upto 50% Off</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="next_button">
                    <img src="assets/img/prev.png" alt="Slider Previous" title="Slider Previous" class="prev" />
                    <img src="assets/img/next.png" alt="Slider Next" title="Slider Next" class="next" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use this example [url](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)

Comment: I'm mostly using the Cycle2 plugin. Works great with pagers + it's responsive. Take a look http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/